All rows being selected in flutter datable when just one row is tapped on
I have a datatable whose row data are obtained from a rest api. I want to be able to select a particular row but all rows are selected instead. How can i fix this problem?
This is my code:
DataTable(
  columns: const <DataColumn>[
    DataColumn(label: Text('ID')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Visitor\'s Name')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Visit Date')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Time In')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Time Out')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Department')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Visitee')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Address')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Phone')),
    DataColumn(label: Text('Purpose of Visit')),
  ],
  rows: List.generate(snapshot.data!.length, (index) {
    var data = snapshot.data![index];
    return DataRow(
        selected: rowSelected,
        onSelectChanged: (index) {
// Handle row selection here
// print('Row ${rowData.id} selected: $isSelected');
          setState(() {
            rowSelected = index!;
          });
        },
        cells: [
          DataCell(Text(data.id.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(data.visitor_name.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(data.visit_date.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(data.Time_in.toString())),
          DataCell(TextFormField(initialValue: data.Time_out.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(data.Department.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(data.Visitee_name.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(data.Address.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(data.Phone.toString())),
          DataCell(Text(data.Purpose_of_visit.toString())),
        ]);
  }).toList(),
);

I tried to add an onSelectedChanged property and when I select a row, it selects every row in the datatable

I think you didn't pay attention to the selected and the onSelectChanged types. So, this part of your code
selected: rowSelected,
onSelectChanged: (index) {
  setState(() {
    rowSelected = index!;
  });
},

is wrong because selected value is boolean but you are assigning an int I guess.
You are using onSelectChanged: (index) {...} you have defined an index before but this new index on onSelectChanged is boolean.

Only one selected row

Now, If you want to have only one selected row, I think you have something like: int rowSelected = -1;. '-1' beacuse at first, no row is selected and you must do something like:
selected: rowSelected == index,
onSelectChanged: (selected) {
  setState(() {
    rowSelected = selected ?? false ? index : -1;
  });
},

In this code rowSelected = selected ?? false ? index : -1; we check, if the selected value can be null, we set is as false, then we check if it is selected or not.

Multiple selected rows

Otherwise if you want to have multiple selected rows, you must change your int rowSelected to something like List<bool> selectedRows = [] to save list of selected indexes and your code should be like:
onSelectChanged: (selected) {
  setState(() {
    selected = selected ?? false;
    if (selected! && !selectedRows.contains(index)) {
      // add to the list if selected but is not in the list
      selectedRows.add(index);
    } else if (!selected! && selectedRows.contains(index)) {
      // remove from list if not selected but is in the list
      selectedRows.remove(index);
    }
  });
},


Thank you very much for the answer.  Could you also help me solve this problem...please  follow the link: link
